# JavaScript formatting numbers in input by commas not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to separate number with commas and I used code block from another question I found here but it's not working as expected

The input

```
<input type="text" name="budget" placeholder="Total Budget" class="form-control">
```

The JS

```
$('input[name=budget]').keyup(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = $(this).val();
    let newValue = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    $(this).val(newValue);
});
```

When I tested this code I faced a problem

I typed 1000 and it showed correctly 1,000

But when I typed another 0 the number returned into this 1,0,000

And every 0 I increase it adds a comma after it like this 1,0,0,0,0,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove commas first

```js
let newValue = value.toString().replace(/,/g,"").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a native solution for formatting numbers
[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

I would use that, instead of a regExp replace.

```
const numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat();
const newValue = numberFormatter.format(value);
```

Comment: Yes, much better than a RegEx solution.  Could also use Number.toLocaleString which accepts country and currency symbol. +1